# How to aggregate calculated measures involving dimension attributes?

Tags: ssas, excel, dimension

The business case is as follows - 
I have a cube of sales transactions and a dimension of parts. One of the attributes of a part is the current cost, which is non-aggregatable. A user needs to model different scenarios based on costs that vary from the current ones.

My solution-
Add an additional field 'Proposed Cost' to the relational table, mark it non-aggregatable and enable writeback. Create a calculated measure multiplying the proposed cost times the qty measure to get an extended cost. I enable what-if analysis in Excel and we're set

The Problem-
Since the standard cost is non-aggregatable, any measures derived from it are as well. I don't get totals along any group in that dimension. There's no reason that the extended costs could not be summed, so I am guessing that this is a consequence of the design of the product.

Is there any way to accomplish this of is my whole plan fatally flawed?